# Flutter - How do I use await inside the streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, firebase-security

I want to use await inside streambuilder. However, if you use async inside, you get an error. On the code below !!!!!!!! That's the part I want to solve. Thank you very much if I can tell you how.

```
class _MemoStreamState extends State<MemoStream> {
final _fireStore = Firestore.instance;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _fireStore
      .collection(widget.logInUsrEmail)
      .orderBy('id', descending: false)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

    final memos = snapshot.data.documents;
    List<MemoMaterial> memoList = [];

    for (var memo in memos) {
      final memoDocumentID = memo.documentID;
      final memoTitle = await PlatformStringCryptor().decrypt(memo.data['title'], _key);  !!!!!!!!!!
      final memoUsrID = memo.data['usrID'];
      final memoUsrPW = memo.data['usrPW'];
      final memoText = memo.data['text'];
      final memoCreateTime = memo.data['createTime'];

      final memoMaterial = MemoMaterial(
        logInUsrEmail: widget.logInUsrEmail,
        doc: memoDocumentID,
        title: memoTitle,
        usrID: memoUsrID,
        usrPW: memoUsrPW,
        text: memoText,
        createTime: memoCreateTime,
      );
      memoList.add(memoMaterial);
    }

    return Expanded(
      child: new ListView.builder(
```

Comment: You cannot use an asynchronous build method. You should edit your stream and yield results when `memoTitle` is defined. See [the docs](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) for help for processing streams.

Comment: The part to edit the stream is" stream: _fireStore
      .collection (widget.logInUsrEmail)
      .orderBy('id', descending: false)
      .snapshots()()," you mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do something like this :

```dart
  Stream<List<MemoMaterial>> memosStream;

  Future<MemoMaterial> generateMemoMaterial(Memo memo) async {
    final memoTitle =
        await PlatformStringCryptor().decrypt(memo.data['title'], _key);

    return MemoMaterial(
      logInUsrEmail: widget.logInUsrEmail,
      doc: memo.documentID,
      title: memoTitle,
      usrID: memo.data['usrID'],
      usrPW: memo.data['usrPW'],
      text: memo.data['text'];,
      createTime: memo.data['createTime'],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    memosStream = _fireStore
            .collection(widget.logInUsrEmail)
            .orderBy('id', descending: false)
            .snapshots()
            .asyncMap((memos) => Future.wait([for (var memo in memos) generateMemoMaterial(memo)]));
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<List<MemoMaterial>>(
    stream: memosStream // Use memostream here
```

[`asyncMap()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) will "transform" every new set of Documents into a list of MemoMaterial, and emit this list into the stream when the action is performed.

[`Future.wait()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Future/wait.html) allows to perform multiple async requests simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your good reply. It was very helpful. But there is still a problem. Even if you define memoStream by using an inventory, it still comes out null inside the list. What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't this read `.asyncMap((memos) => Future.wait([for (var memo in memos)...` (memos instead of documents)?

Comment: @AugustinR I am getting error of `memos` in "for (var memo in memos)" statement. Error is "The type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable." kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: we will have to change it from "[for (var memo in memos)" to "[for (var memo in memos.docs)" to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using FutureBuilder inside StreamBuilder in following way.

```
Stream<List<int>> callme() async* {
    yield [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  }

  buildwidget() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: callme(),
            builder: (_, sna) {
              if (sna.hasData) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: buildwidget(),
                  builder: (_, snap) {
                    if (snap.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: sna.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          return Text("${sna.data[index]} and ${snap.data}");
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to use **Getx** or **Provider** State management to Handle the UI if it depends on the async function.
Suppose you want to fetch data from firebase using `StreamBuilder()` which returns some docs which contains image links then you want to download these images and show from storage. Obviously downloading the image is async type of work. Then you will get error if you show the images with the links you get direct from `StreamBuilder()`.

What you can do is set a variable in getx or provider to show or hide the image Widget. If the Image is being downloaded or not downloaded then set the variable to hide/show the image when the async type of function is completed.