# buffer stream listener's values to feed async function with each single stream value

Tags: file, flutter, dart, stream, listener

I have created a stream listener to sync server data with a local file on the device. On startup it looks for any newer data than seen on the device. However, on startup, this returns a bunch of data more or less simultaneously.

And it appears as if this data would call my function writing any new stream event to the local file multiple times before the function finishes the first write process.

listener:

```dart
// =================================================================== SYNC DATA
  void syncCustomers() async {
    DateTime lastCustomerChange = DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
    final List<Customer> customersLocal = await getAllLocalCustomers();
    if (customersLocal != null)
      for (var c in customersLocal) {
        if (lastCustomerChange.isBefore(c.changeDate))
          lastCustomerChange = c.changeDate;
      }
    _customersSubscription = customerCollection.where('changeDate',
        isGreaterThan: lastCustomerChange.toIso8601String())
        .snapshots().listen(
          (QuerySnapshot snapshot){snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            storeCustomerLocally(Customer.fromEntity(CustomerEntity.fromSnapshot(document)));
        });}
    );
```

storing stream events

```dart
  Future<void> storeCustomerLocally(Customer c) async {
    const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
    final cFile = await _getLocalFile('customers.json');

    List<Customer> customers = await getAllLocalCustomers();
    if (customers == null) {
      customers = [c];
    } else {
      customers.add(c);
    }
    final cJsonString = encoder.convert(customers);
    await cFile.writeAsString(cJsonString);
    print('a');
    return vectorFile.writeAsString(cJsonString);
  }
```

I have removed some code here to make it easier to read. Basically I am splitting the data of each customer into 2 files, which is why I have a line `await cFile...` and `return vectorFile...` at the end of the function. On startup, the print statement is reached only with the last stream value. For the previous statements, the function is restarted when reaching the `await` statement causing only the last stream value to be stored in the file.

UPDATE ================================

Based on pskinks helpful input I have modified the listener to

```dart
final _customersAsyncStream = customerCollection.where('changeDate',
        isGreaterThan: lastCustomerChange.toIso8601String())
        .snapshots().asyncMap((snapshot) async {
          await snapshot.docs.forEach((document) async {
      await storeCustomerLocally(Customer.fromEntity(CustomerEntity.fromSnapshot(document)));
    });
    }).drain();
```

With the function to store each stream event, I have also tried to return a bool as the Future result (in the code above it is void), to see if this makes the difference - it doesn't.

For each event the function is called and in contrast to my initial problem, a document is created on the first run. However, it is empty and after the `await cFile...` statement it re-launches with the the storing function. Then after parsing all events, it starts again looping with the print statement (as shown in the debugger). Then the output file is also populated with data.

Besides some strange JSON error in that file that does not correspond to my stored JSON string, I need the data of each event loop in that file as an input for the loop of the next stream event.

I don't really understand why each function call is divided, breaking and continuing at that `await` statement.

Comment: tried to use `Stream.asyncMap`? the docs say: *"Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.

This acts like map, except that convert may return a Future, and in that case, **this stream waits for that future to complete before continuing** with its result."*

Comment: No, I haven't found this method with my previous searches. Just looking into it how to implement. Happy to accept this as the answer - even happier with 2 sentences how to best implement :-)

Comment: Do I have to create an intermediate stream with asyncMap and then listen to that stream?

Comment: `stream.asyncMap(theAsyncMethodThatreturnsFuture).listen(...)` or ``stream.asyncMap(theAsyncMethodThatreturnsFuture).drain()``

Comment: sorry bothering again, but I don't get this to work. Before your last comment, I also tried `.asyncMap((documents) => Future.wait` from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484143/flutter-how-do-i-use-await-inside-the-streambuilder, which I also did not get to run (nor the one raising that question)

Comment: That made all the difference. Got it, `await` needs a future of course which `snapshot.docs` isn't. Much appreciated!

Comment: nicely illustrated - looks familiar with my initial issue....